# Retrieve emails from domain admin

Tags: google-apps-script

is it possible to retrieve emails of domain users from domain admin ?

i have to create a Google apps script application, which read all emails of domain users and save emails in Gdrive of one account.

Comment: Do you want the email - addresses or email - content/headers/attachments of all emails of all users?

Answer (score 0):

Untested but should do what you want just fine.

```
function myFunction() {
  var users = UserManager.getAllUsers();
  var content = "";
  for (var user in users) {
    content += users[user].getEmail() + "\n";
  }
  DocumentApp.create("Emails Of Users").appendParagraph(content);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another version I use from within a spreadsheet :

```
function findUsers() {     
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  sheet.getDataRange().clear()
  var users = UserManager.getAllUsers();
  var r = new Array();
//
  for( var i = 0 ; i < users.length ; i++ ){
    var Umail = users[i].getEmail(); 
    var UnomF = users[i].getFamilyName()
    var UnomP = users[i].getGivenName()

      if(users[i].getAgreedToTerms()){var Udejaconnect = 'oui'}else{var Udejaconnect = 'jamais'}
//
     r.push([UnomF,UnomP,Umail,Udejaconnect]);
  }   
  r.sort(function(x,y){
  var xp = x[0];
  var yp = y[0];
  Logger.log(xp+'   '+yp)
  return xp == yp ? 0 : xp < yp ? -1 : 1;//  sort on name ascending
}
)
  var header = ['Nom de famille','Prénom','Email','Déjà Connecté?']
    sheet.getRange(1,1,1,r[0].length).setValues([header]).setFontWeight('bold')
    .setBackground('silver').setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true);
    sheet.getRange(2,1,r.length,r[0].length).setValues(r);
}
```